# How to test child components props method in the parent component test

Tags: reactjs, jestjs

I'm writing a test for my parent class which contains a child component. The code coverage reports that I haven't covered test for child components props method. Below is my structure of my components

```
export const CreateSRFullScreenPanel: React.FC<Props> = ({
  interPluginContext,
  srType,
  errorMessage,
}: Props) => {
    const [disableButton, setDisableButton] = React.useState(false);
    const [submitSR, setSubmitSR] = React.useState(false);
    const returnToHomePage = (): void => {
     getRouteClient()
       .changeRoute(getActiveRegionBaseUrl(state.regionName));
    };
    const cancelOp = interPluginContext.isValid()
       ? CancelAction
       : returnToHomePage;
   ...
    <childSR disableButton={disableButton} onSubmitComplete={() => 
     setSubmitSR(false)}/>
   <Button
            type={ButtonType.Submit}
            buttonStyle={ButtonStyle.Primary}
            onClick={cancelOp}
            
   >
            Cancel
   </Button>
};
```

When I wrote a test like below I was getting undefined for method calls.

```
it("check props method gets called", () => {
    const wrapper = mount(
        <ParentSR {...props} />
    );
    console.log(wrapper.find(CreateSR).props().onSubmitComplete()); // undefined
    console.log(wrapper.find(CreateSR).props().disableButton()); // true

  });
```

Also, when I click on a cancel button `cancelOp` method gets called. How do I mock `returnToHomePage` method calls?

Comment: You didn't show what returnToHomePage is, so it's unclear how it can be mocked. ParentSR module is truncated.

Comment: Where is cancelOp used? What is getRouteClient? What is getActiveRegionBaseUrl? Please, provide https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve for your case. Nothing can be suggested regarding how things can be mocked at this moment because it's unknown what are possible options for mocking.

Comment: As I have mentioned cancelOp is used on click of a cancel button. The getActiveRegionBaseUrl looks like below: 
export function getActiveRegionBaseUrl(regionName?: string): string {
  const activeRegionName = !!regionName ? regionName : "phx";
  return BASE_URL_REGION_PATTERN.replace(
    BASE_URL_REGION_PLACEHOLDER,
    activeRegionName
  );
}

getRouteClient looks like below:

export default class RouteClient implements Client {
changeRoute(path: string, method?: RouteChangeMethod): void;
};
export declare const getRouteClient: () => RouteClient;

Comment: Are they in the same module or another one? Please, provide MCVE, it's necessary to give a qualified answer to your question, the question is considered off-topic without it. Currently it misses important parts. There's no cancel button in your example so it's unclear how exactly it's related to the question.

Comment: @EstusFlask updated. Also, why do you think the child props method is returning undefined?

Comment: State setter doesn't return current state, `setSubmitSR(false) === undefined`. It cannot be used to assert the state, in case this was your intention. A place where `submitSR` is used needs to be asserted. But it's not used in the code you posted.